# F10 key is always turned on in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-backlight

F10 key is always turned on in ubuntu 18.04 but not in windows. I am currently using duel boot ubuntu with windows 10. I am newbie in ubuntu and don't have any knowledge of this type of problems . I have searched so many times but could not find any relative answer.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! what is the symptom? how can you tell that F10 is "always turned on"?

Comment: After boot into ubuntu it turns on. Thanks Joshua Besneatte.

Comment: Are you specifically talking about the backlight for that key being on? Or are you saying that the key behaves as if it's being pressed (sends a signal)?

Comment: Not backlight it is a small indicator light as like caps lock key has.